How to change the default home path in Laravel 11?
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Cache\RateLimiting\Limit;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Support\Providers\RouteServiceProvider as ServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\RateLimiter;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

class RouteServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * The path to your application's "home" route.
     *
     * Typically, users are redirected here after authentication.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    public const HOME = '/home';

  
    public function boot(): void
    {
      RateLimiter::for('api', function (Request $request) {
            return Limit::perMinute(60)->by($request->user()?->id ?: $request->ip());
        });$this->routes(function () {
            Route::middleware('api')
                ->prefix('api')
                ->group(base_path('routes/api.php'));

            Route::middleware('web')
                ->group(base_path('routes/web.php'));
        });
    }
}

I'm currently working with Laravel 11 and encountered an issue where I can't find the HOME constant class that was available in earlier versions. I want to change the default path for the HOME constant, which is currently set to /home. Can someone guide me on how to do this in the latest version

I think you can create your own RouteServiceProvider, this Laracasts question explains in detail.

You can create your own RouteServiceProvider or create a const HOME in any other class you want. Its just a variable.

force recirect by the serveer from / to home/

The HOME constant has been removed from the RouteServiceProvider in laravel 11,Please
set a default redirect path.

Modify the HOME constant.
public const HOME = '/new_path';

Make sure you that you have a route defined for the new home path in your routes/web.php.
Route::get('/new_path', [ExampleController::class, 'exampleMethod'])->name('new_path');


Not relavant in Laravel 11.
